# Automatically save the parent item when creating a child Odoo 16

Tags: odoo, odoo-16

When I create a new object and without saving I want to create a child, I can't do it because the parent doesn't exist yet. How can I automatically save and substitute the parent when creating a child element?

I have no idea where to start. Perhaps, somehow override the create() method.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your scenario and without more details I could tell you that the childs could be records of a One2many field on the parent. So everything will be in memory on the browser until you save the parent.
You could take as an example the Sale Order and their lines. The lines wont be physically created until you save the sale order... but you could define them on the Sale Order Form visually in memory on the browser

If this is not what solve your problem I will need more details around the parent child model that you wanna implement

Comment: So, I try to create child item, but can't to do it, because parent one doesn't create automatically. So, I should firstly create parent one and after that create child one, but I want to create parent one automatically.
[link](https://imgur.com/a/7KbSgY6)

Comment: You aren't very specific about your scenario. Do you want a consultancy call to help you figure out have to move forward?

Comment: Why?
I've already done this through overriding the onchange function in the child model, but it doesn't show up on the UI. So I gave up on this solution.

All I need is that when I open the form to add a child object, create (if it doesn't exist) the current object. Because otherwise it will not be possible to save the child element, because the parent one is not created yet.